# Postgresql - Table size do not refresh

Tags: postgresql

I want to know the size of my Table (postgresql). I make this query:

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('mytable'));
```

Result: 8192 bytes

Then, I add 4 rows and the result is the same (8192 bytes).

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: These 4 rows fit within this 8kb block. Add (much) more data and check again.

Comment: Thanks. I inserted more data and all ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres puts records in fixed-size [pages](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/storage-page-layout.html), which are 8kB each by default. Storage is allocated one page at a time. Once you add enough rows to reach your table's [fillfactor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS), it will add a second block, and the size will jump to 16384 bytes.

Comment: Thanks. I inserted more data and all ok.